# Weird [Morphia] Java Error

Tags: java, json, mongodb, fetch, morphia

recently I started trying to use Morphia for my Bukkit project. I got this error after trying to fetch a model from database.

Error in console:

```
[22:30:01 WARN]: Class not found defined in dbObj: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.test.CNDB.documents.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[?:1.8.0]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[?:1.8.0]
```

Code for getting the Model:

```
public Server getDbServer() {
    if (dbServer == null) {
        Server server = getDatastore().find(Server.class).field("_id").equal(ObjectId.massageToObjectId(Config.Mongo.server_id)).get();
        dbServer = server;
    }
    return dbServer;
}
```

Imports in class containing getDbServer():

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import me.test.CNDB.documents.Server;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;
```

The Config.Mongo.server_id returns 53b0a637ef86581085bff51d, which corresponds to the _id field of a Server.class model in DB.

How can I prevent this error? The model is still fetched success, I am able to print the JSON String.

Comment: Add the error and code as code block to your post — it's much easier to read and the links cannot break / change in the future. And please add the relevant imports, which are probably the issue here.

Comment: Also a test case that removes bukkit from the picture that still reproduces the error.  It's almost certainly something environmental about bukkit, though.

Comment: @evanchooly Okay I just attempted this, there was no error. I cannot reproduce this Morphia error unless Bukkit is trying to do it. Also, I'd like to point out that everything works in Bukkit as well. It's just this error appears at the time I try to fetch a Server.

Comment: Sounds like a bukkit misbehavior then.  Wouldn't be the first time the minecraft guys wrote crappy java.  :)

Comment: @evanchooly Can this error cause any future errors? I'm having no problems right now, it's just this massive error that is worrying me. I'm assuming I can just go ahead and ignore it?

Comment: I don't use bukkit.  I have no idea.

Comment: @xeraa Reformatted. I've added the imports, they don't look like the cause of this problem. I can see why Server might error, but it is pointing at my Server class which is the Morphia Model.